# Error while trying to change the storyboard programically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm getting the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'present'". I'm trying to change the storyboard based on the user device's height.

The error appears on the line: `present(viewC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var width = bounds.size.width
    var height = bounds.size.height

    if height == 2436 {
        //iphone is iphoneX
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewControllerX", bundle: nil)
        let viewC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerX") as UIViewController
        present(viewC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return true
}
```

Comment: How iPhone X height == 2436  ???

Comment: The iPhone X's pixel height count.

Comment: Oh you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're in AppDelegate class there is no function named `present(_: )` that you can make use of.

If you need to present any Viewcontroller from AppDelegate, add the same to the window

```
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as UIViewController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `present` in `AppDelegate` as it's a `UIViewController` instance method you need

```
self.window?.rootViewController = viewC
```

//

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 812 {
        //iphone is iphoneX
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerX") as UIViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewC
     }
     else {

     }

     return true
 }
```